# Android BLE characteristics getValue was deprecated in API level 33, What's correct way can I get that value?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Android BLE characteristics getValue was deprecated in API level 33 and in developer.android [BluetoothGattCharacteristic](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic) said we can use BluetoothGatt#readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic) instead

but as I checked with code and also developer.android mentioned it return a boolean not byteArray
[BluetoothGatt#readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt#readCharacteristic(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic))

What's correct way can I get that value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**In API <= 32:**

Each `BluetoothGattCharacteristic` object contains a `value` field that are mutated both by the application (when writing) and the Bluetooth stack (when reading/receiving notifications).

To write a characteristic value, first set the `value` field (by using the `setValue` setter method), then perform the actual write by calling `writeCharacteristic`.

To read a characteristic value, call `readCharacteristic` (which triggers the Read Request to the remote device) and in the `onCharacteristicRead` callback which is called when the response arrives, retrieve the value by getting the `value` field (by calling the `getValue` getter method).

When receiving a notification or indication using `onCharacteristicChanged`, retrieve the value in the same way as in the read callback.

Note that `getValue` simply returns whatever current value is stored in the local `value` field of the `BluetoothGattCharacteristic` object. It does not trigger a new Read Request to the remote device. Usually, `getValue` should never be called except immediately in the `onCharacteristicChanged` or `onCharacteristicRead` callbacks.

**In API >= 33:**

The new API does not make use of any `value` field. Instead the value is passed as a parameter.

To write a characteristic value, simply call `writeCharacteristic` and pass the value as parameter.

To read a characteristic value, first call `readCharacteristic`. When the response arrives from the remote device, the `onCharacteristicRead` callback is called with the just read value as a parameter.

When receiving a notification or indication using `onCharacteristicChanged`, the value is passed as a parameter to that method.

**Apps supporting both new and old devices**:

Note that code compiled for the new API will not work correctly when run on older devices. What you will notice is that the new callback overloads will not be called at all. You have basically two options here:

1. Stick with the old API and ignore the new API. As long as this old API is not completely removed, code will continue to work as before, even in newer devices.
2. Implement both APIs and *do not* call `super.onCharacteristicChanged(...)` etc. For old devices the old API method will be called (only) and for new devices the new API method will be called (only). I suggest you to have the body `onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic, characteristic.getValue());` etc. in the old callback API method in order to manually pass the data to the new callback, and put all your logic in the new callback API method.

**Why was this API updated?**

Consider the case when you have a characteristic that allows both notifications and writes. If the Android app writes to a characteristic at the exact time a notification arrives, then there will be a race condition regarding the `value` field of the characteristic object, meaning you might either write the just notified value, or be notified of the value you are just about to write. The new API solves this by passing the value directly as parameters.

Comment: Why not call `super.onCharacteristicChanged(...)`?

Comment: @Christian See here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/modules/Bluetooth/+/cb9e6608ae439f8ab435460b896aae4e421132e6/framework/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.java#159. If the new overload is not overridden, the old callback will be called on Android >= 13. If you override but call super, then both overloads will be called (not what you want). So if you don't call super, only the new callback will be called, as wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Calling only the `BluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic()` is not enough, you must also
implement the `BluetoothGattCallback` interface wherever you manage your BLE
transactions in order to get a value from remote BLE device.
Let's say you manage your transactions in a class called **MyBluetoothManager**.

`BluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic()` function does not return a value immediately,
instead, it initiates a bluetooth read transaction in which the remote device
will **asynchronously** respond later. It works like an internet connection, you make
a request to a server to get some data, then the server asynchronously responds
later and finally you process data in its response callback.
The value is returned when you invoke `readCharacteristic` method is a value that
indicates whether the read operation was initiated successfully.

**EDIT** Added both `onCharacteristicRead` methods for supporting both below API 33 and API 33+.

Here is the **MyBluetoothManager** minimal code example:

```
class MyBluetoothManager implements BluetoothGattCallback {
    
    public interface ReadListener {
        void onValueObtained(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, byte[] value);
    }
    
    private ReadListener readListener;
    
    // Instantiate the following vars in the relevant callbacks
    private BluetoothGatt connectedPeripheral;
    private BluetoothGattCharacteristic interestedCharacteristic;
    ...
    
    // A wrapper function for #BluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic. It also
    // a ReadListener type parameter in order to notify the caller asynchronously.
    public boolean readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                      ReadListener readListener)
    {
        if(connectedPeripheral == null || characteristic == null) return;
        this.readListener = readListener; // register the listener from activity
        return connectedPeripheral.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }
    
    
    public BluetoothGattCharacteristic getInterestedCharacteristic() {
        return interestedCharacteristic;
    }
    ...
    
    // Other callbacks goes here...
    /*
     * This callback method is added in API 33
     */
    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead (BluetoothGatt gatt, 
                                      BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, 
                                      byte[] value, 
                                      int status)
    {
        // According to the new API you can only get the value in this callback.
        // You can copy and deliver value to another parts of application,
        // or handle it instantly here.
        
        if(readListener != null) // Notify the activity for the new obtained value
            readListener.onValueObtained(characteristic, value);
    }
    
    /* The older callback method that is deprecated in API 33 */
    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, 
                                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 33) {
            if(readListener != null) {
                readListener.onValueObtained(characteristic, characteristic.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Other callbacks goes here...
    ...
}
```

Here is an example for `MyBluetoothManager.readCharacteristic` method invocation
from an activity:

```
class BLEControlActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private MyBluetoothManager mBluetoohManager;
    ...
    
    private Button readButton;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mBluetoohManager = // instantiate depending on your implementation
        ...
        readButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonRead);
        readButton.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
            if(mBluetoohManager.isConnected()) {
                mBluetoohManager.readCharacteristic(
                    mBluetoohManager.getInterestedCharacteristic(),
                                                    (characteristic, value) -> {
                                                        // Handle the reead value
                                                    }
                )
            }
        });
    }
}
```